# Azure form-recogniser fails with umlaut and Danish Ø

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services, azure-form-recognizer

I've been using Azure form recogniser for about a month now, and I've tried with with a variety of forms and European languages. However recently I've run into what I believe is a bug. That's when I use their UI through the dockerized label tool `mcr.microsoft.com/azure-cognitive-services/custom-form/labeltool` which exposes a web app for labelling and training.

I am working on a German document, and for some reason the UI will ignore umlauts and danish O, even before training and most definitely after.
Is this something anyone has run into before, is there a solution or a compromise to be made? I know this is a long shot, but I thought it's worth asking.

Answer (score 1):

The current version of service doesn't fully support those European languages yet.

Comment: I am confused, because it clearly detects umlauts and accents, as well as Danish Ø. I have screenshots where it has detected them just fine. What puzzles me is that it detects them once, and then stops detecting them!

Comment: There might be some bugs or configuration changes in the preview releases.  We're working on getting more language support online.  please stay tuned.  thanks.

Comment: Hey @XinZou, thanks for the reply. Let me know if you need a screenshot of what I'm talking about, it makes it very clear to see what the problem is.

Comment: could you try our new version (2.1-preview.1),  also you can use our labeling tool for this preview version at: https://fott.azurewebsites.net/

Comment: I am no longer working on this so I can't really try it. Sorry!